# spring security based on active directory permission groups

Tags: spring, security, active-directory-group

How can I restrict access to web resources based on permission groups rather than roles in spring security?

For instance, suppose I have a permission group called `Domain\Developers`, how can I use it for access control?

I've tried to find a solution using expression based access control. Something similar to:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('USER_ROLE')" />
```

But instead of using `hasRole` I'd expect to have something like `inGroup()`. Couldn't find anything so far.

Could it be that there's no implementation out there for what I ask for and I'd have to implement it myself?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how groups work in AD.  Newer versions of spring security support group tables but they are for organisational purposes only, ie. you can't say allow access for this particular group, you can only use authorities (roles) associated with the group.

Comment: Thanks, Jax.
But theoretically, I could implement a custom UserDetailsService that populates the authorities with the groups a user belongs to, and that we'll do the work. Am I right?

Comment: I believe I found how to do it:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.il/2013/07/role-based-access-control-using-spring-security-ldap-authorities-mapping-mvc.html